# How to keep a transient variable as part of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to show a variable (which is actually a List) as part of f.select(..) function in Rails3.2, so that the selected value is stored in a different attribute in the ActiveRecord object. How do I declare the above List variable as a transient variable in ActiveRecord, so that ActiveRecord doesn't try to store this.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. Give examples, what's your code?

Comment: Maybe the OP wants to know about declaring transient variables in ActiveRecord classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own getter and setter methods in the model like this (don't forget to add it to attr_accessible):

```
def virtual_attr=(value)
  self.real_attr = value
end

def virtual_attr
  self.real_attr
end
```

or just create an alias for the real attribute, like this:

```
alias_attribute :virtual_attr, :real_attr
```

Answer (score 3):

In rails 4+, you can define a transient field in your model simply via:

```
attr_accessor :the_field
```